# The RedisCommandExecutionException, while Spring Data Redis execute CONFIG, GET command in the Redis server

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis, amazon-elasticache

I have a Spring Boot 3 based project. Which uses the Ridis server as DB.
It is a simple project and everything is auto-configured by spring-boot-starter-data-redis module

The entity:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@RedisHash
public class ValidatedPhone {

  @Id
  private String phoneNumber;
  @Indexed
  private int profileId;
  @TimeToLive
  private long timeToLive;

}
```

The repository:

```
public interface ValidatedPhoneRepository extends CrudRepository<ValidatedPhone, String> {}
```

The configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "redis", name = "enabled", havingValue = "true")
@EnableRedisRepositories(enableKeyspaceEvents = 
RedisKeyValueAdapter.EnableKeyspaceEvents.ON_STARTUP)
public class RedisConfiguration {
}
```

Properties file:

```
spring:
  data:
  redis:
    host: ${redis.server.url}
    username: ${redis.server.user}
    password: ${redis.server.password}
    ssl:
      enabled: true
```

Locally, with Redis 6.2, everything works fine. The problem happens when the project is deployed to AWS Cloud with **AWS Elasticache Redis**.

The exception

> Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: ERR unknown command `CONFIG`, with args beginning with: `GET`, `notify-keyspace-events`

Probably AWS Redis has some restrictions for executing the CONFIG command.

My by I need some custom redis configuration to avoid calling CONFIG command? Or my be some other solution?

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution in [the Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis.repositories.expirations).

In case it will be useful for someone.
It turns out that the problem was the annotation.

```
@EnableRedisRepositories(enableKeyspaceEvents = RedisKeyValueAdapter.EnableKeyspaceEvents.ON_STARTUP)
```

The annotation by default tries to set up the "Ex" value for the key notify-keyspace-events in Redis.

There is a note about that in the Spring docs
[image]

The solution was to add parameter keyspaceNotificationsConfigParameter="" which prevents the attempt of setting the key value

```
@EnableRedisRepositories(enableKeyspaceEvents = RedisKeyValueAdapter.EnableKeyspaceEvents.ON_STARTUP,
    keyspaceNotificationsConfigParameter = "")
```